# Is it possible to tween the red color to blue?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I have some code I wrote in the [book of shaders editor](https://thebookofshaders.com/edit.php#02/hello_world.frag):

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif


uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

float remap(float a, float b, float c, float d, float t) {
    return ((t - a) / (b - a)) * (d-c) + c;
}

float outline(vec2 st) {
    return smoothstep(0.99, 1.0, st.y) + smoothstep(0.99, 1.0, st.x) + smoothstep(0.01, 0.0, st.y) + smoothstep(0.01, 0.0, st.x);
}

float mouseFoo(vec2 scaledSt, vec2 u_mouse, float scaleVal) {
    vec2 scaledMouse = u_mouse * scaleVal;
    if(scaledSt.x < ceil(scaledMouse.x) && scaledSt.x > floor(scaledMouse.x) && scaledSt.y < ceil(scaledMouse.y) && scaledSt.y > floor(scaledMouse.y)) {
    // if(u_mouse.x < 100.0) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        return 0.0;         
    }

}

void main(){    
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.03,0.07,0.15);
    vec3 redColor = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec3 outlineColor = vec3(1.0);
    float floorSt;
    float scaleVal = 5.0;
    vec2 scaledSt = st * scaleVal;

    // tile
    st *= scaleVal;
    floorSt = floor(st.x);
    st = fract(st);

    // inner color
    color = mix(color, redColor, mouseFoo(scaledSt, u_mouse/u_resolution.xy, scaleVal));

    // outline
    color = mix(color, outlineColor, outline(st));

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0 );
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the red color tween to the blue color when a box is hovered off?  I think I might have an idea of how to do it if I were to write data to a texture and look that up, but even then I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml)

Use `mix` to interpolate between red and blue. You need another variable that transitions from 0-1 to do the blend, which is `mix`'s 3rd parameter.

[ShaderToy example](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/3ddSz7):

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    // Normalized pixel coordinates (from 0 to 1)
    vec2 uv = fragCoord/iResolution.xy;

    vec3 red = vec3(1,0,0);
    vec3 blue = vec3(0,0,1);

    // Output to screen
    fragColor = vec4(mix(red, blue, uv.x),1.0);
}
```

which produces:

[image]

In your case, you'll want the 3rd parameter (the alpha or lerp parameter) to be driven over some time (say, .2 seconds) after the mouse entered the hover area. You'll need to do one of the following:

- Detect the hover entered at a higher level and then pass the mouse down time in as a uniform
- Drive the 3rd parameter directly from a uniform

Comment: Thanks for the reply Doug!  I'm familiar with the mix function, but I'm wondering how it's possible to know that a square has been unhovered and to start the transition to blue?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, read the question too fast. My fault. Updated.